# Parsing JSON via Java - Array with key->value format

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I've a problem using gson (JSon Java library from Google).

I've to parse a result like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 28 Oct 2000 16:46:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 217

{
  "key_1":"value_1",
  "key_2":"value_2",
  "key_3": [
    {
      "key_3_1":"value_3_1",
      "key_3_2":0,
      "key_3_3":1
    }
  ]
}
```

I've written this class:

```
import java.util.List;

public class ObjectClass {
    private String key_1;
    private String key_2;
    private List<SubArray> key_3;

    public static class SubArray {
        private String key_3_1;
        private boolean key_3_2;
        private boolean key_3_3;
    }

    public void printList() {
        System.out.println("Size: " + key_3.size());
    }
}
```

and into MainClass I have:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ObjectClass obj = gson.fromJson(br, ObjectClass.class);
```

where br it's a buffered reader that contains buffer of requested web page.
Parsing of key_1 and key_2 works fine but parsing of key_3 downs' work.
Have you a suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It probably doesn't recognize `0` and `1` as `boolean` values. Try changing those members of `SubArray` to be `int` instead, or else write your own deserializer as described here: [GSON False uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722773/gson-false-uppercase)

Answer (score 1):

Change some types in `SubArray`.

```
public static class SubArray {
    private String key_3_1;
    private int key_3_2;
    private int key_3_3;
}
```

The following code shows that `key_3` is parsed correctly.

```
public void printList() {
    System.out.println("Size: " + key_3.size());
    System.out.println("key_3_1: " + key_3.get(0).key_3_1);
    System.out.println("key_3_2: " + key_3.get(0).key_3_2);
    System.out.println("key_3_3: " + key_3.get(0).key_3_3);
}
```

The result is:

```
Size: 1
key_3_1: value_3_1
key_3_2: 0
key_3_3: 1
```